# Key names of associative arrays

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a nested associative array like this:

```
$inputTypes= array( 
    "natural" => array(
        "text",
        "password",
        "textarea",
        "radio",
        "checkbox",
        "file"
    ),
    "hybrid" => array(
        "image",
        "date" ,
        "url",
        "email"
    )
);
```

I want to print its key names, applying code shown below:

```
foreach ($inputTypes as $inputs){
    echo key($inputTypes).'<br>';
}
```

but i get this output

```
hybrid
hybrid
```

How can i get name of each keys, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach ($inputTypes as $key => $value){
    echo $key.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
foreach ($inputTypes as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The foreach counter is conflicting with the internal array pointer.

```
$c = count($inputTypes);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    echo key($inputTypes).'<br>';
    next($inputTypes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $key => $val

```
$inputTypes= array( 
        "natural" => array("text", "password","textarea", "radio", "checkbox", "file"),
        "hybrid" => array("image", "date" , "url", "email")
);

foreach ($inputTypes as $key => $val){
    echo $key.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach ($inputTypes['natural'] as $n)
    echo "$n<br/>";

foreach ($inputTypes['hybrid'] as $h)
    echo "$h<br/>";
```